# Php rss show just image in $description part

Tags: php, rss, feed

There is a method that removes the image...

How can i just use the image shown by src="..." in the $description part and remove the description text?

```
<?php
       $html = "";
       $url = "http://newsfeed.zeit.de/index";
       $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
       for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++){
           $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;

           //removes image
           $description = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $description);

           $html .= "$description";
       }
       echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: You could preg_match the IMG tag, then add that image HTML to the $html variable

Comment: so just replace it with preg_match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd first alter your regex slightly to match the images, then append this to your `$html` variables instead of the `$description` like so:

```
$description = "Venenatis Adipiscing Aenean Mollis <img src='http://www.domain.com/images/cat.gif' /> Justo Egestas Nibh";
preg_match("/(<img[^>]+\>)/i", $description, $matches);
if (isset($matches[0])) {
    $html .= $matches[0];
} else {
    $html .= $description
}
```